# Why am I getting errors when I try to run the "Normalized cuts" demo?

Tags: matlab, demo

I am trying to use the normalized cuts package from [http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jshi/software/Ncut_9.zip][1] (on Windows 7  - MATLAB R2010a 32 bits), but it's not working. I'm trying to run the demo called "Ncut Clustering demo" and I got the following error:

```
??? Undefined function or method 'sparsifyc' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ==> ncut at 41
W = sparsifyc(W,dataNcut.valeurMin);

Error in ==> ncutW at 9
[NcutEigenvectors,NcutEigenvalues] = ncut(W,nbcluster);

Error in ==> demoNcutClustering at 27
[NcutDiscrete,NcutEigenvectors,NcutEigenvalues] = ncutW(W,nbCluster);
```

I already put the NCUT9 dir in the path so this is not the problem I guess, and I already compile the MEX files with the command: `compileDir_simple(mydir)`.

Comment: It can't find the function `sparsifyc`.  Double check the directory of where normalized cuts is, and look for this function.  Make sure it's there.

Comment: It is there. It's a C++ function with MEX function.

Comment: I noticed the same when I downloaded that code. It could be that the MEX function is incompatible with yours (and my) MATLAB release.  Your question seems similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852192/running-old-mex-file-on-new-matlab-releases) so you may want to check it out and try to download the C++ code and re-compile.